# infinite loop error. Nothing goes into the output file

Tags: c++

My code keeps breaking at the second while loop. Can someone help please.
the file input is it is the name of the student then the ID# then the grades of said student. I have been working on this for some time and i just can get it to work.
I would be grateful if someone could help me with this code.

Input file record format:

```
Bob Marley

1234567

5 75 90 100
```

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inputFile;
ofstream outputFile;
string studRecord;
string stud_ID;
int count_sat = 0;
int count_Average = 0;
int count_unSat = 0;
int stud_count = 0;
int validGrade = 0;
int invalidGrade = 0;
int grandTotal = 0;

double grade_average = 0;
double class_average = 0;

inputFile.open("StudRecord.txt");
outputFile.open("GradeReport.txt");
if(inputFile.is_open())
{

    while (!inputFile.eof()) //getline (inputFile,studRecord)
    {

        getline (inputFile,studRecord); //Getting name
        outputFile << studRecord << '\n';
        stud_coups nt++;

        getline (inputFile,stud_ID); //Getting ID


        int grade;

        while (inputFile.peek() != '\n')
        {

            //inputFile.get();
            inputFile >> grade;

            if(grade < 0 || grade > 100)
            {
                invalidGrade++;
            }
            else
            {
                validGrade++;
            }
        }

        //inputFile.get();
        if(validGrade != 0 )
        {
            grade_average = stud_count / validGrade;
        }

        grandTotal += grade_average; // grandTotal = grandTotal + grade_average

        if (grade_average >= 85 || grade_average <= 100)
        {
            count_sat++;
            //cout <<" Progress : Satisfactory" << endl;
        }
        else if (grade_average >= 65 || grade_average <= 85)
        {
            count_Average++;
            //cout << " Progress : Average" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            count_unSat++;
            //cout << "Progress : Unsatisfactory" << endl;
        }


        validGrade = 0;
        invalidGrade = 0;
        grade_average = 0;
        stud_count= 0;

    }
    }
    else
    cout << "Unable to open file";

    class_average = grandTotal / stud_count;

   outputFile << studRecord << endl;
   outputFile << "Number of Valid Grades: " << validGrade << endl;
   outputFile << "Number of Invalid Grades: " << invalidGrade << endl;
   outputFile << "Grade Average: " << grade_average << endl;
   outputFile << "Progress: 85-100: Satisfactory, 65-85: Average, 0-65: Unsatisfactory " << endl;
   outputFile << "________________________________\n" << endl;
   outputFile << "Student Count: " << stud_count << endl;
   outputFile << "Satisfactory Count:" << count_sat << endl;
   outputFile << "Average Count: " << count_Average << endl;
   outputFile << "Unsatisfactory Count:" << count_unSat << endl;
   outputFile << "Class Average:" << class_average << endl;

   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.close();



   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Try to check peek() against the eof flag instead of '\n'. `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`

Comment: Is there a newline between each two lines in the input file?

Answer (score 0):

When the file stream come to the end, `peek()`will return -1, which will lead infinite loop, you should test it like this:

```
    int next_char;
    while (next_char = inputFile.peek(), (next_char != '\n') && (next_char != -1) )
```

And I don't know why you reset these varibles:

```
    validGrade = 0;
    invalidGrade = 0;
    grade_average = 0;
    stud_count= 0;
```

it will lead an exception: Integer division by zero when `grandTotal / stud_count`.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd loop `while (inputFile.peek() != '\n')` is likely reaching the end of the file and causing an infinite loop due to `peek()` returning `EOF` instead of `'/n'`

Your program should exit loop if `inputFile.peek() == EOF`

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

if your file has data in same order i would suggest this

```
while (inputFile.peek() != EOF || (!isalpha(inputFile.peek()))
```

this will work for files like this
Bob Marley
1234567
5 75 90 100
Balaji Ram
1265466
4 54 54 98